# Creating a custom token in firestore for a user in another firestore instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am trying to create an Admin CRM for an application that I am working on. To do this I have a cloud function connected to the main application that creates a custom token for a user on the CRM application. They way that I create that token is as follows:

```
  return admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid, {admin: true}).then((token: string) => {
                    console.log('Custom ID created!');
                    return  res.status(200).send(token);
                })
```

I then login as a user in the CRM, passing the uid back to this function. On creation of the token, I then pass that into  the firestore function `signInWithCustomToken(token)`. The main signin function mentioned is as follows:

```
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(user): Observable<any> {
        return from(this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password))
            .pipe(
                flatMap((res: any) => this.createAdminCustomtoken(res.user.uid)),
                flatMap((token: any) => this.signInWithToken(token))
            );
    }
```

However when I send this request I get the following error:

[image]

It is my understanding that this error is because I am trying to provide a token from one project in another - However, this behavior is something that I need to do. Is there a workaround for this? or is there a better method.

Answer (score 0):

Tokens minted with the Firebase Admin SDK can only be used on the project that the Admin SDK is initialized with.

You cannot create tokens with the Admin credentials from one project and then sign in with that token on another project. That would be a pretty big security risk if it was possible.

Instead you will have to initialize the Admin SDK with the credentials of the other project, and use that to mint the token.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Just a couple of questions: 1. Are you saying i need to set up a separate admin SDK for the CRM project?
2. If so, I receive the token from this project, but how do I then use that token to allow me access to data from the original project? I.E How do I pass that token into the firebase rules of the main app to allow read, write access on all collections?